# Change the numbers of pages Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I was wondering if we could change the numbers of the pages ?

Let say I'v got 10K lines rendered by 1000 lines on each page. so we've got 10 pages and I've set 5 buttons so I've got pages 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and the navigation buttons.

I'd like to insert for exemple "..." instead of the last page button (5 in our case) when I've got more than 5 pages.

Thank you for any help !

```
const defaultOptions = {
    // Datas
    columns: tableColumns,
    ajaxURL: props.ajaxURL,

    // Layout
    pagination: 'remote',
    ajaxFiltering: true,
    ajaxSorting: true,
    paginationButtonCount:5,
    paginationSize: 50,
    paginationSizeSelector: [10, 50, 250, 1000],
    layout: "fitColumns", // fitColumns, fitDataTable, fitDataStretch, fitDataFill, fitData,
    responsiveLayout: "collapse",
    height: '100%',
    keybindings: true,
    cellVertAlign: 'middle'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text of the "last" page button to be "..." you can do this in the localisation options:

```js
const defaultOptions = {
    langs:{
        default:{
            pagination:{
                last:"...",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full details can be found in the [Localization Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/localize)

Comment: Hi Oli,

Thank you for your response, but I'd like to change it only if there's more page... As in my exemple, I've got 10 pages so on the first page we can see page 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. So I'd like to change this last number until there's more page behind. Not sure if it's possible though... Cheers

Comment: that isnt possible im afraid but there is a next button that performs exactly the same function which you could change the copy on using the same method as above

Comment: If that's not possible, fine. I will find a solution by maybe adding all the results so the user will know how many lines he has. Thanks again for your time Oli